# jQuery find по массиву элементов

Tags: jquery

Как правильно произвести поиск в массиве элементов?

```
var html = '';
var elements = undefined;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    html += '<span class = "a"></span>';

elements = jQuery(html);
console.log(elements.find('.a').length);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/180c5ge3/

Comment: может ищет только с родительским тегом `elements = jQuery('<div>' + html + '</div>');`

Comment: @Ivan Matthews , да, так можно, но я думал - возможно, есть методы поиска по массиву элементов.

Comment: а где здесь массив элементов, собственно?

Comment: @СергейМишин

    Object(5)
    0: <span class="a">
    1: <span class="a">
    2: <span class="a">

Объект.

Comment: объект. а поиск нужен в массиве. хм...

Comment: А искать-то что надо?

Comment: @СергейМишин это суть придирки. Нужен поиск в структуре, получаемой посредством указанного выше кода. Как сделать поиск своей функцией - я знаю, интересует именно то, почему jQuery не работает с таким объектом при помощи своих методов.

Comment: @СергейМишин console.log(elements.find('.a').length);

Comment: @nup потому что в документации сказано, что *.find()*
Осуществляет поиск элементов внутри **уже выбранных элементов**. А где тут *уже выбранный* элемент?

Comment: @СергейМишин, значит, никак кроме `.wrap` > `.unwrap`?

Comment: @nup не знаю что такое ".wrap > .unwrap", но нужен корневой элемент. По-сути как это написал Ivan